# Belavia Airlines, Negative Covid test required?

Tags: air-travel, germany, covid-19, berlin, belarus

I'm travelling to Minsk, Belarus with Belavia Airlines from Berlin, Germany. I plan to stay there for one month and have all the Visa requirements etc.
I wanted to know if I need a negative Covid test to be able to be on the flight?

Comment: The requirement for tests depends on the country of origin and other facts such as how long you were there before traveling. It is not possible to answer this question just with the data provided.

Comment: @Itai more information has been provided

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the airline you will need proof of a negative covid test to fly into Belarus:

> Passengers must have a printed medical certificate with a negative
> Coronavirus (COVID-19) PCR test result issued at most 72 hours before
> arrival. The certificate must be in Belarusian, English or in Russian.

This information was [updated on October 23](https://travelbans.org/europe/belarus/) and from the list of press announcement travel restrictions have been changing quite frequently. Check the info often as your travel date approaches. Also I advise you to have a printed copy of the latest rules with you. I recently traveled to Europe and found that nearly every agent had read a different version of the rules. When I insisted each time, showing them the latest information, they allowed me to go through either right away or after validating with a supervisor. Even the arrival form handed before landing on the plane was outdated and I had to explain that rules recently changed.